# Network not found when running SPEC2017 in GEM5 se mode

Tags: omnet++, gem5

When I compile 520 in x86 config file and run them use the command line:

```
./omnetpp -c General -r 0 > omnetpp.General-0.out 2>> omnetpp.General-0.err
```

it **works fine**. But when I run the same command line in **GEM5**, it occurs an error:

> <!> Error: Network `largeNet' not found, check .ini and .ned files.

**Both methods run under the SPEC default XXX/run path.** How to solve the problem.

### work directroy

```
# wangkaixuan @ user-PowerEdge-T640 in ~/SPEC2017/benchspec/CPU/520.omnetpp_r/run/run_base_refrate_wkx-x86-m64.0000 [16:36:45] 
$ ls
General-0.sca.cmp  compare.err  compare.stdout  ned                    omnetpp.General-0.out  omnetpp_r_base.wkx-x86-m64  speccmds.err  speccmds.stdout
compare.cmd        compare.out  control         omnetpp.General-0.err  omnetpp.ini            speccmds.cmd                speccmds.out
```

### run in host

**Cmd**

```
$ ./omnetpp_r_base.wkx-x86-m64 -c General -r 0
```

**Output**

```
OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2008 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 4.0, build: 090310-10709, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer
Setting up Cmdenv...
Loading NED files from a SPEC directory 13

Preparing for running configuration General, run #0...
Scenario: $repetition=0
Assigned runID=speccpu-runid
Setting up network `largeNet'...
Initializing...

Running simulation...
** Event #1   T=0   Elapsed: 0.000s (0m 00s)  0% completed   ev/sec=0
```

### Run in Gem5

**Cmd**

```
$ /home/data/userhome/wangkaixuan/Workspace/gem5-for-debug/build/X86_MESI_Two_Level/gem5.opt \
    --outdir=/home/data/userhome/wangkaixuan/Workspace/gem5-for-debug/mydebug \
    /home/data/userhome/wangkaixuan/Workspace/gem5-for-debug/configs/example/se.py \
    --num-cpus=1 --mem-size=8GB --cpu-type=DerivO3CPU --caches --l2cache --l1i_size=64kB --l1d_size=64kB \
    --fast-forward=10000000000 --maxinsts=1000000000 \
    -c /home/data/userhome/wangkaixuan/SPEC2017/benchspec/CPU/520.omnetpp_r/run/run_base_refrate_wkx-x86-m64.0000/omnetpp_r_base.wkx-x86-m64 \
    --option="-c General -r 0"
```

**Output**

```
OMNeT++ Discrete Event Simulation  (C) 1992-2008 Andras Varga, OpenSim Ltd.
Version: 4.0, build: 090310-10709, edition: Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE
See the license for distribution terms and warranty disclaimer
Loading NED files from a SPEC directory 0

Preparing for running configuration General, run #0...
Scenario: $repetition=0
Assigned runID=speccpu-runid

<!> Error: Network `largeNet' not found, check .ini and .ned files.


End.
```

Answer (score 1):

Under gem5 se mode, `system call readdir` is not implemented. Which is needed by glob in omnetpp. I just use another way to load the ned files.

```cpp
int NEDResourceCache::doLoadNedSourceFolder(const char *foldername, const char *expectedPackage)
{
    PushDir pushDir(foldername);
    int count = 0;

    char buf[1024];
    getcwd(buf,1024);
    ev.printf("\ncwd: %s\n", buf);

    int numFiles = 13;
    std::string filelist[13]{"EtherAppCli.ned", "EtherBus.ned", "EtherHost.ned", "EtherLLC.ned", "EtherSwitch.ned", "MACRelayUnit.ned",
            "MACRelayUnitPP.ned", "EtherAppSrv.ned", "EtherEncap.ned", "EtherHub.ned", "EtherMAC.ned", "LargeNet.ned", "MACRelayUnitNP.ned"};


    // FileGlobber globber("*");
    const char *filename;
    ev.printf("foldername: %s\n", foldername);

    for (int i = 0; i < numFiles; i++)
    // while ((filename=globber.getNext())!=NULL)
    {
        filename = filelist[i].c_str();
        ev.printf("filename: %s\n", filename);
 
        if (filename[0] == '.')
        {
            continue;  // ignore ".", "..", and dotfiles
        }
        // if (isDirectory(filename))
        // {
        //     count += doLoadNedSourceFolder(filename, expectedPackage==NULL ? NULL : opp_join(".", expectedPackage, filename).c_str());
        // }
        else if (opp_stringendswith(filename, ".ned"))
        {
            doLoadNedFileOrText(filename, NULL, expectedPackage, false);
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for much for this, lifesaver. For anyone unsure about how to properly edit spec source files here's what I had to do: make this change under `520.omnetpp_r/src/simulator/nedresourcecache.cc` then add `strict_rundir_verify=0` in your spec config. This'll then work when you compile 620.omnetpp_s too. I also got compilation errors with copy pasting this directly, so I had to delete lines using `ev.printf` and change `std::string filelist[13]{...` to `std::string filelist[13] = {...` (and make sure you don't accidentally copy that onto two different lines!)

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify in command a directory where NED files are located using `-n` option:

```
... --option="-c General -n /home/data/userhome/wangkaixuan/xxxx -r 0"
```

where `/home/data/userhome/wangkaixuan/xxxx` is the path to folder that contains NED file with `largeNet`.

Comment: Indeed, specifying the NED path may solve the issue, but the actual cause of the issue is that certain files (like NED files) are loaded relative from the current working directory. To have the same behaviour, you should use the same working directory for both command line.

Comment: I have tried to specify the NED directory by set `ned-path` in file `omnetpp.ini`, add `-n` command line, and set the `$NEDPATH` environment. And no use.

Comment: I'm sure both command line run in same work directory
`/home/data/userhome/wangkaixuan/SPEC2017/benchspec/CPU/520.omnetpp_r/run/run_base_refrate_wkx-x86-m64.0000`

Comment: The line `Loading NED files from a SPEC directory 13` suggests that there is `SPEC` folder with your NED files. Could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76463666/edit) the question and add the path to that folder as well as the content of `SPEC` folder?

Comment: Thanks for you impiration. I have resolved the problem.